# If used with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) , and if used without @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) , what will the method return

Tags: java

@GET
        @Path("/onboardingStatus")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Onboard fetchStatusData(@QueryParam("cc_id") String ccid) {

        return copIntegrationService.fetchStatuses(ccid);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your service, model class?

Comment: Model class-   @Data
public class Onboard {
    private List<OnboardingStatuses> onboardingStatusesList;
}

Comment: service class-  public Onboard  fetchStatuses(String ccid) {
        Onboard onboard=new Onboard();
        List<OnboardingStatuses> onboardingStatusesList = prospectInfoDao.fetchStatusData(ccid);
        onboard.setOnboardingStatusesList(onboardingStatusesList);
        return onboard;

    }

Comment: basically i need to ask the return value that we will get @Produces annotation is used and if its not used